# How to achieve below situation using python list comprehension?

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

```
rows = [(d = re.split("\s{2,}|\|", line)) for line in lines if len(d) > 5 and d[0]!='' ]
```

As in the code snippet shown, I am splitting a list of lines by spaces in each line. I am trying to assign split to a variable `d` so that I can use it later in if condition and can avoid repetitive split.

Is there way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rows = [d for d in [re.split("\s{2,}|\|", line) for line in lines] if len(d) > 5 and d[0]!='']
```